# JavaScript Burger Button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hamburger-menu

On click of a burger button I want "site-navigation-menu" to appear and take up the whole screen. At the moment nothing happens when I click on my burger button, not even a console log. However, if I change my JS to say on click of "body", my "site-navigation-menu" *does* appear.

```
<div class="burger" id="burger-6">
    <span class="line"></span>
    <span class="line"></span>
    <span class="line"></span>
</div>
```

When i change ".burger" to "body" the js works.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".burger").click(function() { 
    console.log("work plz");
    $(".burger").toggleClass("is-active");
    $(".site-navigation-menu").toggleClass("show");
    $(".line").toggleClass("burgerColor");
    $(".burger").toggleClass("burgerFixed");
});
});
```

My burger is inside header.html which I reference from index.html like this:

```
$(function() {
     $("#header").load("header.html");
     $("#footer").load("footer.html");
});
```

Could this be causing any problems?

Comment: Put your code in a jsfiddle to demo it.

Comment: have you included jquery library in your page?

Comment: The only reason I can see that it wouldn't work is that if the `.burger` element was not in the DOM when your document ready event was fired. Is it added afterwards, perhaps through an ajax method or some other event?

Comment: My .burger is added later via a Media Query. Also, see my edit

Comment: post all the code also the site-navigation-menu sample code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regards to your edit, yes that definitely is the problem. The content is being added dynamically, so you should call the click function in the following way -

```
$("body").on('click', '.burger',function() { 
  console.log("work plz");
  $(".burger").toggleClass("is-active");
  $(".site-navigation-menu").toggleClass("show");
  $(".line").toggleClass("burgerColor");
  $(".burger").toggleClass("burgerFixed");
});
```

This will directly reference the body and then check for the dynamically added class.

Comment: I have all of those styles. Shall i post all my burger styling too?

Comment: Yes sure. 

But it could also be the way you are including your Jquery script file. Send that through to. You usually want Jquery locally and a cloudbased link (backup) in the head.